# Android: how to get the name of apk file programmatically?

Tags: android, file, apk

For some reasons, my app can be installed with different apk names. At launch, I would like to know what is the name of the apk file. Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: better is to try some [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name/5841353#5841353) before posting a question

Comment: Thanks Adil but it doesn't answer my question. I want to get the name of the apk file which has been copied to the device, not the application name or package name. Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 5):

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String apkName = "example.apk";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + apkName;        
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(fullPath, 0);
```

you can got it with:

```
info.versionCod
```

and

```
info.versionName
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

The apk or app name can be retrieved using package manager.
According to alex's answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30348666/2026280

Assuming you have the path of the apk file.

```
public static String getAppLabel(PackageManager pm, String pathToApk) {  
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(pathToApk, 0);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
    // those two lines do the magic:
    packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir = pathToApk;
    packageInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = pathToApk;
}

CharSequence label = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
return label != null ? label.toString() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ActivityManager actMngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
string runningPkg = actMngr.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(runningPkg , 0);
```

Added:

If you are not getting the apk name then you can compare it with intalled pkg and get the corresponding app name. You can fetch the installed app's pkg name and app name like this:

```
ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    String description = (String) p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(pm);
    String  label= p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
//Continue to extract other info about the app...
}
```

Note: Add this permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: i think this give only package name not apk name

Comment: it is difficult to get apk name because it rename at sign time

Comment: totally different apk name and package name.

Comment: what you will set only that you will get corresponding to pkg name.

Comment: i don't get you! what you say?

Comment: Hi Vineet. I initilly thought that your code works but it is actually not the case. Indeed, if I change the name of my apk, the properties of applicationInfo variable remains unchanged: ai.dataDir remains unchanged, ai.packageName remains unchanged, ai.sourceDir remains unchanged... Any solution ?

Comment: Yes. What I can see when exploring the content of the phone on which I ran the app is that the apk name is changed to "pkg.apk" whatever the apk name is. Consequently, it seems not possible to know what was the name of the apk before installation. This "pkg.apk" file is installed in /mnt/asec/package_name I have the feeling that getting the original name of the apk before installation is not possible... Tell me if you find a solution.

Comment: @Regis_AG, year is `2020` any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved with **[getPackageArchiveInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPackageArchiveInfo(java.lang.String,%20int))** from an already packaged apk file:

```
  PackageInfo package_info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(file_path_to_apk, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work for me:

```
String versionName = "null"; //String apk versionName
                int versionCode = -1; //int versionCode
                String APKFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/apkname.apk"; //For example
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo    packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(APKFilePath, 0);
                // the secret are these two lines
                packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir       = APKFilePath;
                packageInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = APKFilePath;
                Drawable APKicon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm); //drawable apk icon
                String   AppName = (String)packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm); // String apk name
                    versionName = packageInfo.versionName; //String version name
                    versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode; //int version code
                    apk_icon.setImageDrawable(APKicon);    //ImageView apk icon
                    Apkpackage.setText(packageInfo.packageName); //TextView apk package name
                    Apkname.setText(AppName); //TextView apk name
                    Apkversion.setText(String.format("Version Name: %s Version Code:%d", versionName, versionCode)); //TextView versionName and versionCode
```