# can I take info from apk

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have a question, can I take info from apk file?? I have to compile my app one time but change the name for several times, I would like to take the info from apk file but I can´t take the apk name (only the package name following these posts [How to get the file *.apk location in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635448/how-to-get-the-file-apk-location-in-android-device/9424662#9424662) and [Android: how to get the name of apk file programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608173/android-how-to-get-the-name-of-apk-file-programmatically))

Is it possible??
Thanks everbody

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  What info do you need to get?

Comment: A string (is that what you mean)

Comment: No, that's not what I mean.  What kind of information are you looking for?  File name, app name, version number, version string, icon, etc. - what do you need?

Comment: Sorry, I need the apk name but I obtain package name

Comment: Why would you need to get the name of the apk?

Comment: Your package is going to have to be unique on the Play Store.  How do you anticipate using the application name (assuming that's really what you're after)?  If you're truly after the APK name just look in your project's /bin folder.

Comment: @Dodge I have to add a code in the apk name and I have to take it

Comment: @BillMote the apk won´t be in Play Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to add a code in the apk name and I have to take it

1) Users can give a downloaded file any name they want.
2) Android renames apk during installation
e.g.
you put `yourapp-yourcode.apk` on your SD card and install it.
in `/data/app` (where android creates a copy of installed files) the file will be named `this.is.your.package.name-?.apk` where the `?` is a number (in my /daga/app folder, it is 1 or 2)

=> You should find another location to place your code.

Comment: That´s all the info I take the most close to the apk name is the package name, as you said your.package.name-?.apk and that´s not what I want, but thanks anyway

Comment: you can't find what you want, as ANDROID renames the file during installation.

Comment: You may want to accept the question. Even if its not what you wanted to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you have obtained package name , then you almost done.
try this one.

```
Package myPackage = Manifest.class.getPackage();
    String specTitle = myPackage.getSpecificationTitle();
    String vendor = myPackage.getSpecificationVendor();
    String virsion = myPackage.getSpecificationVersion();
```

specTitle will return you the name if available else it will return 'unknown'

Comment: It returns Unknown so it´s not availabe, why is it?

Comment: You should have to provide name and all information when you have build your .apk file add your file information in MANIFEST.MF file.
Then it will return the proper name.