# How to read content of apk file programmatically?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-sdk-tools, dex

I need read the content of `apk` file (including `AndroidManifest.xml`) programmatically. I know there are some tools like `apktool`, `dex2jar`, `aapt` to extract apk content but, I need to do the same **through an Android application**. By the way **my start point is a valid apk file path**.

Comment: Is it like listing the information of the .apk or all the class files inside that ? Make It Clear.

Comment: @NayanRath I need to read both `AndroidManifest.xml` and `source files`.

Comment: Is this needed for Virus Scanning.Just Asking Coz i am also doing the same and having some issues.

Comment: I will look for issues and let You know !!!

Comment: something like it, I'm working on an advanced APK Inspector.. Thanks for your care.. @NayanRath

Answer (score 4):

See this answer on another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850406/55940

Basically you can use this:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(file.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
```

This would only get the meta data though... You would have to use a ZipInputStream etc to read the content of the file.

Answer (score 3):

First of all get the apk file from its path by this code

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
                try {
                    packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("PACKAGE NAME HERE", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                File file = new File(packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: after I get uri from file, how can I read apk content (i.e. manifest file, etc..)?

Comment: you could read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/4761689#4761689  and this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469147/get-android-apk-file-versionname-or-versioncode-without-installing-apk

Comment: So what's happened, any success?

Comment: no, it works for installed applications because it uses `PackageManager`.