# Getting name of original .APK file in Android

Tags: java, android, apk, android-applicationinfo

I am trying to figure out how to get the name of the original .apk file from which an application was installed. I know that you can retrieve the package name and the source directory of the installed application by using the `ApplicationInfo` class (described here: [Android: how to get the name of apk file programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608173/android-how-to-get-the-name-of-apk-file-programmatically)) but this is NOT what I want.

As an example, suppose I have a simple application that is named `TestApp` (via the `android:label` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file). Furthermore, suppose I generate an .apk file for the application above, rename said .apk file to `TestApp_JohnDoe.apk`, and then email that application to John Doe for installation. When John Doe installs the application by clicking on the .apk file I would like to be able to read the filename of the original .apk, `TestApp_JohnDoe.apk`, that I sent to him. Using the `ApplicationInfo` class, more specifically the `sourceDir` method gives me the install directory and application name, `/data/app/TestApp.apk`, which is not what I am looking for. I know that it is probably possible to scan all available directories looking for the original .apk file, but I am hoping to avoid this.

In summary, I would like to programatically retrieve the .apk filename/source directory of the installer .apk, such as `/storage/sdcard0/Download/TestApp_JohnDoe.apk`, as opposed to the .apk filename/source directory of the actual installed application, `/data/app/TestApp.apk`.

Comment: What makes you think that the file still exists and is in a place that is readable by your app, for every possible installation path?

Comment: Well that is what I am wondering -  if a provision exists for determining the name of the original .apk file. It could be possible that, even if the original .apk file was deleted, the installation process makes a note of the name of the original .apk file that is then available from within the application; that is what I am trying to determine.

Comment: First, I am not aware that this information is recorded. Second, in general, there is no requirement that the APK file used for installation have a recognizable filename. Just because *you* named the file `TestApp_JohnDoe.apk` does not mean that the *email client* will name it `TestApp_JohnDoe.apk`, when it makes a temporary copy on external storage for brief use during installation. Put your identifiers *in the app*, whether via compiled in (see Bojan's answer), packaged in `assets/`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to let the app know the apk name that was set at compile time, if that is of any use to you

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // Change the target apk file name and path
    String apk_path = "$rootProject.projectDir/bin"
    String apk_name = "john_doe.apk"
    project.delete(project.apk_path) //Delete any remains
    String apkFile = String.format("%s/%s", apk_path, apk_name)
    variant.outputs[0].outputFile = new File(apkFile)
    // This can be used in Java runtime by using getString(R.string.apk_name)
    resValue "string", "apk_name", apk_name
}
```

But what you are asking, I am pretty sure it is not possible