# Getting my own .apk file name

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the file *.apk location in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635448/how-to-get-the-file-apk-location-in-android-device)

How should I get the my own application name , including path which is installed on android phone.
Through code it should happen.

Comment: Plz Be More Specific about ur question......

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/9424662/691639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about [getPackageResourcePath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageResourcePath%28%29) 
and 
[getPackageArchiveInfo(archiveFilePath, flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)