# How to find the apk path on android?

Tags: android, directory

I installed my android app(apk file) on my phone, when I go to my files: i can't find my com.myappnamefoler.net in folder(/sdcard/Android/data). is there a default path?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635448/how-to-get-the-file-apk-location-in-android-device/9424662#9424662

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in `data/data/com.myappnamefoler.net`

Answer (score 1):

You should find in `/system/app` or `/data/app`

Comment: unless your phone is rooted, you cannot access /data/app/ where installed applications are present , this path is protected.

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the files in the folder provided by `getFilesDir()` , it will be in  the folder `/data/data/<your.package.name>/files` in the root of your **system**, not on your sdcard. (To view this, your phone needs to be rooted)

If you saved the files in the folder provided by `getExternalFilesDir()`, it will be in the folder `/sdcard/Android/data`, `/sdcard0/Android/data` or a similar directory.