# How can my android app open another app, automated with appium?

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, appium, android-uiautomator

I want to automate an installed app on my android device using appium.

**Questions:**

- I want to automate a flow in an app like Facebook, say I want to do a
  FB post on my wall. How can I do this with [appium](http://appium.io/)?
- How can I still
  run the automation? [Please read below]
- Can I create my own app that just opens other app?

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596959/how-to-find-the-apk-path-on-android) I see I cannot configure the path to this app if my device isn't rooted.

`unless your phone is rooted, you cannot access /data/app/ where installed applications are present , this path is protected.`

Comment: What is your exact requirement...You want to open any third party app like whatsapp, fb from your app???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Activity from another Application Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839176/launch-activity-from-another-application-android)

Comment: actually i want to automate a flow in an app like facebook. say I want to do a FB post on my wall. How can I do this with appium?

Comment: @bofredo  
He is asking about how to automate flow of other app by writing his own app. Example : 1) Using AutoIT script to automate opening a URL or executable and perform button clicks or whatever using the automation script without Human intervention. 2) A CRON script to automate tasks in *NIX

Answer (score -1):

For any automation you need a .apk for the application to perfrom automation if you dnt have that then it is not possible to automate such apps. If you have .apk files then you can create two drive instances and automate the communication between two apps.

Comment: He is asking about how to automate flow of other app by writing his own app. Example : Using AutoIT script to automate opening a URL or executable and perform button clicks or whatever using the automation script without Human intervention.