# Why does System.getProperty("user.dir") return "/"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the path of my current running apk on android.
I'm using System.getProperty("user.dir").
But it gives out a "/", which is the root directory of the Android system.
Am i missing something?

Comment: And what do you expect it to be ?

Comment: @kocko I was mroe expecting a "/user/apk/myapkname"...something like that

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) says, the `user.dir` property is the user working directory, which is not necessarily the same as the directory where your apk is placed.

Anyway, the `List<ApplicationInfo> PackageManager.getInstalledApplications()` will give you a list of the installed applications, and `ApplicationInfo.sourceDir` is the path to the `.apk` file.

Here's some sample code:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

for (ApplicationInfo app : pm.getInstalledApplications(0)) {
  System.out.println("SourceDir: " + app.sourceDir);
}
```

The above will give you the sourcepath for all the installed apks.

*The example is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635448/how-to-get-the-file-apk-location-in-android-device).*

Answer (score 1):

Your apk is located at `/data/app/<your_package_name>` after installation on the internal memory. This path is consistent across Android, and you don't need to use `System`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. The functions you want are:

- getDir() -- returns e.g. "/data/data/com.example.myapp/app_foo"
- getFilesDir() -- returns e.g. "/data/data/com.example.myapp/files"
- getCacheDir() -- returns e.g. "/data/data/com.example.myapp/cache"
- getExternalFilesDir() -- returns e.g. "/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures"
- getExternalCacheDir() -- returns e.g. "/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp/cache"

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sourceDir) class is your answer:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

for (ApplicationInfo app : pm.getInstalledApplications(0)) {
  if (app.packageName.equals(appPackage) { Log.i( app.sourceDir); }
}
```

Hope that sorts you.